# JCarousel widget on Yii framework don't load image

Tags: yii, jcarousel, yii-extensions

I'm trying to use JCarousel widget on Yii framework.

My JCarousel must show images of specific user that belong to a specific gallery (for that user).
I retrieve the information about the images from a MySQL DB, in the specific from Photos table, where gallery_id have a determined value. The column from Photos table that contain the name of the photos is "path".

In the code I have written this:

```
$DataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Photos', array('criteria'=>array(
                                        'condition'=>'gallery_id = :id',
                                        'params'=>array(':id'=>$gallery->id),
                                   ),));

$this->widget('ext.JCarousel.JCarousel', array(
                   'dataProvider' => $DataProvider,
                   'thumbUrl' => '"/images/upload/".$data->id."_".$data->path',
                   'imageUrl' => '"/images/upload/".$data->id."_".$data->path',
                   'target' => 'big-gallery-item',
                   'vertical' => false,
         ));
```

With this code I get, on the div, the written message: "No result find"

Where I did i go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check your dataProvider. Try get results via `$DataProvider->getData()` and check that you photos exists.

I do not think that the error in the extension, most likely you do not select data from the database.

Comment: Yeah, you hit the nail.  
I had not thought to Provider, convinced it was correct.  
  
Now JCarousel show the structure, but no image.  
No errors found on application.log (thus the images are found).  
  
Have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Open Google Developer Tools panel in Chrome and search js errors.
And< other solution, that your must use Yii::app()->baseUrl for image/thumbnails urls. `Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/upload/" . $data->id . "_" . $data->path`